# How to change aspect ratio or resolution, without needing to rewrite all code Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resolution, aspect-ratio

Recently I thought: "Let's set the 'resolution' from 16:9 to 16:9(1920x1080)" but i noticed that now all my positioning* code was off, and the size of pictures and text was way too small.

My problem now is, if I should just use the 16:9 aspect ratio or an fixed resolution (I don't know the benefits). But if I shouldn't use the aspect ratio, how to change the fixed resolution when the Project is ready, for example in the settings, without needing to rewrite all my code* and rescale all my images on the Canvas according to the resolution.

*For those of you who don't know what I mean with 'positioning', I mean setting the position of an Image on the Canvas, which obviously needs to be changed because the resolution is different. You could make something that detects your resolution and positions you image based on that, but idk if there is a better solution.

Comment: I would assume you are referring to an screenspace-overlay, unity has some [tools for controlling scaling](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/creating-a-screen-space-overlay-ui#5f864d50edbc2a0769e6472c), does these tools help?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is during positioning ui using procentage also canvas Type which is displayed to resolution.
https://youtu.be/Tys6QWi9RpM
Solution on yt.